# In a perfect world, all the graphics and layout are defined in stylesheets - but not <img> src? Shouldn't be?

Tags: html, css, web

The purpose of CSS is to help web developers to define and apply graphics and layout,  separated from the actual content.

However, it seems like CSS can tweak pretty much anything (graphics wise) on a website - apart from the source attribute of an `<img>`-tag.

To achieve 100% separation between style and content (which we all want, right?) shouldn't we define image sources in the CSS as well?

I know that CSS can't do this (no support of changing src-attribute for images) but there are work-arounds, such as using `<div>` with backgrounds instead of `<img>`. However, by doing that, won't it break search engines?

My question is. Is using  instead of `<img>` to achive 100% separation between style and content a reasonable action?

Comment: Actually, you *can* change `<img>` content with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/r3pFn/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`<img />` tags are intended to be content, not style.
`<img />` is supposed to be used for something like a photo accompanying an article.

UI graphics should be done using CSS backgrounds.

Comment: I would add that any "style" done with `<img />` is wrong and should be done with css.

Comment: As SLaks mentioned, <img /> is for content not layout and should be separated as so. Any images that are used for layout should be held in a <div> background.

Answer (score 2):

An image is content - e.g. diagrams. Style is just to make the page pretty but adds nothing to the content (syntax/semantics) of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes images *are* content and not just style... and that's when you use an `img` tag.

Comment: Images should _always_ be content and not style.

Comment: Like an icon to signify that it's an external link? It's merely a style, adding no content, and should be CSS.

Comment: That's rather pedantic, isn't it? You didn't know that when I said "Images" that I meant "images inserted into the page through the use of img tags?" Silly.

Answer (score 1):

Images can very well be part of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Images that are part of the UI should be defined in CSS where possible.

Images that are part of content should be inline img tags.

Answer (score 1):

It depends when. Sometimes the images are content and not style. Therefore you can use div's with css backgrounds if it's purely for style but use the  tag when you want to show a content image.

Then you will truly have a 100% content/style separation.